# VUE how can i submit a form and update the state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

so basically im trying to update the state when a user is creating an account. so far, i can only do it with one single input such as fName, lName, email... but i want to fire both at the same time.. for example.. in data(){ newUserAcc: {fName,lName,email}} then send this and update it on the store. i have attached both files, the vue and the store.js.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app
      style="background-image: url('https://blog.modsy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/D2_Full.jpg')"
    >
      <v-container class="pa-12">
        <v-row>
          <v-card class="pa-16">
            <v-card-title>
              Tenant
            </v-card-title>
            <v-form>
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_fName"
                label="First Name"
              />
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_lName"
                label="last Name"
              />
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_email"
                label="email"
              />

              <v-row>
                <v-btn rounded color="black" class="white--text" href="/acc-for"
                  >Back</v-btn
                >
                <v-btn
                  @click.prevent="addUser_fName"
                  rounded
                  color="black"
                  class="white--text"
                  >Next</v-btn
                >
              </v-row>
            </v-form>
          </v-card>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newUser_fName: "",
      newUser_lName: "",
      newUser_email: "",
      newUser_choosePW: "",
      newUser_confirmPW: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
      "ADD_USER_FNAME",
      "ADD_USER_LNAME",
      "ADD_USER_EMAIL",
      "ADD_USER_PW",
    ]),
    addUser_fName: function() {
      this.ADD_USER_FNAME(this.newUser_fName);
      this.newUser_fName = "";
    },
    addUser_lName: function() {
      this.ADD_USER_LNAME(this.newUser_lName);
      this.newUser_lName = "";
    },
    addUser_email: function() {
      this.ADD_USER_EMAIL(this.newUser_email);
      this.newUser_email = "";
    },
    addUser_pw: function() {
      this.ADD_USER_PW(this.newUser_pw);
      this.newUser_pw = "";
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style></style>
```

```
import vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.use(vuex, axios);

export default new vuex.Store({
    state: {
        fname: [],
        lname: [],
        email: [],
        pw: [],
        newUser: [],
    },
    getters: {},
    mutations: {
        ADD_USER_FNAME: (state, user) => {
            state.fname.push(user);
        },
        ADD_USER_LNAME: (state, user) => {
            state.lname.push(user);
        },
        ADD_USER_EMAIL: (state, user) => {
            state.email.push(user);
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: May I ask why each field is separated from another? You could have just create an array of objects consisting of that fields and just create only one mutation to add a user.

Comment: @rjcarl - Thats actually what I want to do but I just cant figure it out how to do it. I researched so much and all they show is how to fire up one at a time

Comment: Ive just posted an answer, there are some parts that you need to edit based on your preferences. But that is likely the structure that you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you have a store like this...

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: []
  },
  mutations: {
    addUser: (state, payload) => {
      state.users.push(payload.user); // add your newly registered user to the user state
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addUser: ({ commit }, payload) => {
      commit('addUser', payload);
    }
  }
});
```

And in your form component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app
      style="background-image: url('https://blog.modsy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/D2_Full.jpg')"
    >
      <v-container class="pa-12">
        <v-row>
          <v-card class="pa-16">
            <v-card-title>
              Tenant
            </v-card-title>
            <v-form>
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_fName"
                label="First Name"
              />
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_lName"
                label="last Name"
              />
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_email"
                label="email"
              />

              <v-row>
                <v-btn rounded color="black" class="white--text" href="/acc-for"
                  >Back</v-btn
                >
                <v-btn
                  color="black"
                  class="white--text"
                  @click="registerUser"
                  >Next</v-btn
                >
              </v-row>
            </v-form>
          </v-card>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    ...
    data() {
      return {
        newUser_fName: "",
        newUser_lName: "",
        newUser_email: "",
        newUser_choosePW: "",
        newUser_confirmPW: "",
      }
    },
    methods: {
      registerUser() {
        fetch('register/endpoint') // request is optional, if you wan to add the user to your database. If not, you can just dispatch the action 
          .then(() => {
            // if Request is a success, the user will be added to the user state
            this.$store.dispatch('addUser', {
              first_name: this.newUser_fName,
              last_name: this.newUser_lName,
              email: this.newUser_email,
              password: this.newUser_choosePW
            })
          })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```